# Given P(BC)=0.4 ,P(B|AC)=0.5,P(A|B)=0.6 How come my answers are wrong?

Tags: probability

> Given P(BC)=0.4        P(B|AC)=0.5     P(A|B)=0.6
>
> Find the following probabilities:
>
> P(A)
>
> P($A^c|B^c$)
>
> P($B^c and \,A$)

I calculated P(A)=0.52 P(A and B)=0.36

moving on to P($A^c|B^c$)

The solution I got was

P($A^C|B^C$)=$\frac {P(A^c \, and \,B^c)}{P(B^c)}$ =$\frac {(1-P(A))*P(B^c)}{P(B^c)}$=$\frac {P(B^c)-P(B^c \, and \, A)}{P(B^c)}$=$\frac {0.6-(0.6*0.52)}{0.6}$=0.48

The solution I got for P($B^c and \,A$) is:

P($B^c and \,A$)= $P(0.6 * 0.52)$ = 0.312

I feel that I must have missed something these questions seem there are more to it than that?

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: How did you get $P(A^c\cap B^c)=(1-P(A))P(B^c)$?

Comment: $A^C$ and $B^C$ are not independent of each other, so you can not calculate $P(A^C$ and $B^C)$ by take their products.

Comment: @LEANHDUNG so unless the question explicitly states that P(A) and P(B) are independent, we assume that they are dependent ?

Comment: Rather, you cannot pressume they are independent without a reason to do so.